# Remove subdiretories by level

Tags: bash

I have following directory structure:

```
/level1-root
  /level2-a
    /level3-aa
    /level3-ab
  /level2-b
    /level3-ba
```

How can I remove all level 3 directories and their contents without touching level1 and level2?

Comment: Noway. level3 is belong to level2. You can't remove it without modifying level2.

Comment: Do you mean `rm -rf */*/*`?

Comment: Be careful with `rm -rf */*/*` or similar. I think it will remove directories *and files* starting at some level. If you target this at level 3 directories then you will remove level 3 files as well (i.e. files directly under level 2 directories). `rm -rf */*/*/` should target directories only. Additionally `*` doesn't match hidden files/directories.

Comment: Then `rm -rf */*/*/*` followed by `rmdir */*/*`...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you remove `level3-ba` then `level2-b` will lose one of its entries, so it's not "without touching" level 2.

If you want to remove only level 3 directories with their contents (i.e. not to remove files that are directly under level 2 directories, nor anything at level 2 nor level 1), then it's a job for `find -mindepth ... -maxdepth ... -type d ...`. Safe command:

```
find /level1-root -mindepth 2 -maxdepth 2 -type d -exec echo rm -rf {} +
```

- Why `2`? Because your level 3 is 2 directories deeper than `/level1-root` when we start.
- After you confirm you get directories you want, omit `echo` to perform actual removing.